# Updating bound values aynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following asynchronous method in a WPF project:

```
private async void RecalculateRun(Guid run_number)
{
    // kick off the Full recalculation
    //
    await FullRecalcAsync(run_number);

    // When thats done, asyncronously kick off a refresh
    //
    Task RefreshTask = new Task(() => RefreshResults());
    await RefreshTask;      
}
```

The first `await` does a load of calculations and the second takes the results and updates some bound variables. I wasn't expecting the UI to update during the second `await`, but I was expecting it to do so when it finished. Of course, this doesn't happen. Also, I'd just like to point out that if I call `RefreshTask` synchronously after the first `await`, it works fine.

Comment: [`async void` should only be used in event handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) and `RecalculateRun` doesn't look like one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a task without starting it. You need to call `Start`:

```
Task RefreshTask = new Task(() => RefreshResults());
RefreshTask.Start();
await RefreshTask;
```

Or better off use `Task.Run`

```
await Task.Run(() => RefreshResults());
```

Using the `Task` constructor directly is usually discouraged:

> In general, I always recommend using `Task.Factory.StartNew` unless the particular situation provides a compelling reason to use the constructor followed by `Start`.  There are a few reasons I recommend this.  For one, it's generally more efficient

From ["Task.Factory.StartNew" vs "new Task(...).Start"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/06/13/10024153.aspx)